# How do I unlock the museum collectibles in Puzzle Craft?

Tags: puzzle-craft

I have been playing Puzzle Craft, and trying to unlock the collectibles such as the cards, chess pieces, etc.  Obviously, to a certain extent, the drops are random, which makes it hard to tell whether I'm on the right track or not.

The ones I've received so far have been in chests.  What level of chest is required for each level of collectable?  Are there any other ways to earn them?

Answer (score 1):

You can only find the collectible items in chests. There is a building to upgrade the type of chest appearing, which will improve the chest to mythic when maxed.

The type of chest only determine the type of collection items you can found. When you have mythic chests its only matter of luck.

You can build/upgrade your chapel in order to improve your chances of finding collection in chests.